# replacing constant value in java Regex with other value if it matches that Regex

Tags: java, regex

i learn little bit about java regex and in my project i have to do some text replacement. for example i have this line

> db.articles.Find(112);

i want to replace every occurrence of Find with byId that matches this regex

> \s[a-zA-Z]+(\.)[a-zA-Z]+(\.)Find\([0-9]+\);

i write this java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String data = " db.articles.Find(112);";

   String regex = "\\s[a-zA-Z]+(\\.)[a-zA-Z]+(\\.)Find\\([0-9]+\\);";


   data = data.replaceAll(regex, "byId");

   System.out.println(data); // output is byId 

   // but i want output something like this -> db.articles.byId(112);

}
```

but it is not working as expected

Example input

```
db.articles.Find(12);
dbContex.users.Find(1);
Db.libs.Find(50);
```

Example output

```
db.articles.byId(12);
dbContex.users.byId(1);
Db.libs.byId(50);
```

Comment: Why regex? You can very well do a `replaceAll(".Find(", ".byId(");`

Comment: @PradeepPati `replaceAll` *is* using regex, and what you wrote won't work because `.` and `(` must be escaped.

Comment: for example if input file has this line `someObjec.Find(123)` i do not want this to replace with byId , what's why i am using Regex.

Comment: @Andreas you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replaceAll()` method replaces the entire matched string with the replacement value, so you need to *capture* the parts you want to keep, and insert them in the replacement value:

```
replaceAll("\\b([a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.)Find(\\([0-9]+\\);)", "$1byId$2")
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fL8kK5/3) for demo.

Changes applied:

- Replaced `\s` with `\b` (word boundary)
- Removed capturing of periods (`(\\.)` -> `\\.`)
- Added capturing of text before and after `Find`
- Added captured text to replacement (`$1` and `$2`)